# Why I'm keep getting "Access denied: Could not open port" error?

Tags: python, iot

I'm working on a Python project to connect a counting scale to computer with a RS232 and validate the kitting process. Example, if a part is required to have 2 nuts, I want the program to get the data from the counting scale and make sure the quantity of the part on the scale meets the requirement. But, I'm keep getting this error:

> could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)

I verified the port settings in Device Manager and they seem to be all correct. I even tried contacting my company's IT department if they are blocking anything and that came negative. Not sure what is the problem here.

I recently also learned that the counting scale company have their own software.

Could this error caused by the counting scale instead of computer port? How to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have `COM3` open with any other software? Also, can you show a bit of code that reproduces the error?

Comment: Before attempting this in Python, have you succesfull read out the the signal of the scale using any [serial port monitor](https://www.virtual-serial-port.org/articles/best-serial-port-monitor-utilities/)?

Comment: @Axe319, I don't think so. 

`def printWeight():
    ser=serial.Serial(port="COM3", baudrate=9600, timeout=None, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=8)
    
    #closes the port and opens it every time the program runs
    if not ser.isOpen():
        ser.open()
    print("COM3 is open", ser.isOpen())`

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I don't have any other serial port monitor. How to do this, I maybe could try

Comment: @Shashi I've always used puTTY to troubleshoot serial connections.

Comment: Did you read the link?

Comment: @Axe319 I'm still getting same access denied error in putty.

`Opening '\\.\COM3': Error 5: Access is denied.`

Comment: My troubleshooting steps would be: Reboot your computer. This ensures that nothing has left the port open accidentally (perhaps in the program you wrote). Try opening it in puTTY immediately on boot. If you are still getting permissions errors it _may_ be because of a security policy set by your sysadmin, however IMO not likely. The other possibility is another program or antivirus may have blocked communication to that port.